# How to patch eurosym+marvosym for common usage?

Tags: macros, packages, errors, patching

I have a document that uses symbols both from the [`marvosym`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/marvosym/) package as well as the [`eurosym`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/eurosym/) package. There are two commands that clash and I get an error message (due to  `\newcommand` being used and leading to the error `Command \EUR already defined.`).

What is the appropriate way to patch a package? What I have done - in the meantime - was to modify the `marvosym.sty` file and to place it in the document directory.

Comment: Surely, you don't mean to tell us that one of the packages tries to redefine `\newcommand`, do you? Anyhow, I can load both packages without any conflict. And both of them are old (eurosym is from 1998, marvosym from 2006). What version are yours?

Comment: @Harald I do get the error `Command \EUR already defined' (and have modified the question to make it clearer). The packages are from new distributions Marvosym from 2006 and eurosym  as you mentioned 1998.

Comment: Ah, now I see. `marvosym.sty` uses `\newcommand`, but `eurosym.sty` uses `\def` to define `\EUR`. I had loaded marvosym first, so I never saw the conflict.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To just avoid the error, you could declare the affected macro to be undefined:

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
\let\EUR\undefined
\usepackage{marvosym}
```

If you would like to use symbols of both package with originally equal name, you could use the [`savesym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package.

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\savesymbol{EUR}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{marvosym}{EUR}
...
\EUR\ vs. \marvosymEUR
```

[image]

Comment: @ Stefan, thanks never thought of using \let\EUR\undefined

Comment: `\let\EUR\relax` would work as well.

Comment: @Stephan I just came across the `\AtBeginPackage` macro and I thought I would add this as a comment `\AtBeginPackage{marvosym}{\let\EUR\relax}` for completeness.

Comment: Just an obvious note of caution: `\savesymbol` fails for commands with optional arguments. It thus can't be used 'out of the box'.