# Issue with Oxford Bioinformatics LaTeX template

Tags: templates

I downloaded LaTeX Bioinformatics template and when I do the following I get my images in a clean 4 rows and 3 columns filling up one entire page:

[image]

But if I repeat the same code with some other 12 images (or the same images as above) LaTeX does not output any images for the second use of the code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The template obviously does not include your code nor can we, please amend your question to include your MWE of \documentclass{bioinfo} down to \begin{document} and include just enough of the above figure code to show on first but not second page  (replace 1A 1B 1C with example.pdf example.pdf example.pdf) NOTE the template suggests these should be 350 dpi EPS images or 1200 !! when including line art

Comment: May not be related but this class [does weird things](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339408/106162)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the issue by simply removing the file called `stfloats.sty`. Bioinformatics is changing floats in some weird buggy way. If you are OK with a hack, this seems to work.

Comment: This is likely to cause problems at the typesetting stage. I would recommend never directly modifying publisher template code, but rather patching (e.g. via [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch/)) the class or style(s), when needed. (It's not clear from this question precisely how to do so.)